# How Premiere pro-like dynamic rendering effects works?

Tags: opengl, webgl, rendering, shader

You know, each track item of Premiere pro can have dynamic number of rendering effects like *Blur*, *Mosaic*, *Noise*, ... and they can be added/removed in anytime.

My question is, how this can be done dynamically? As I thought, those thing might happen on fragment shader level so some of my thoughts are :

1. Every shader code is combined into one single shader file and controlled by shader parameter(boolean to on, off) on rendering time.
2. Draw each level on single draw call and pass the result image to next level as a texture. (Draw image with *Blur* shader and make the result as a a texture then pass it to *Mosaic* shader...)
3. Create and compile shader code dynamically on every effect is added/removed.

But every 3 solutions seems to be very inefficient and expensive.

Does anyone know how it works actually?

Comment: No idea what premiere does, specifically, but each method is viable. (1) would be uber-shaders, (2) is multi-pass rendering and (3) dynamic code generation. Neither of which is particularly inefficient. Heck, there's a whole 2D software rasterizer, that performs dynamic code generation to speed up exactly those composition operations you wonder about: https://blend2d.com/performance.html

Comment: [Solution 2](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-image-processing-continued.html) as there are tons of effects that are impossible to accomplish by combining shaders. Solution 1 would not work because effects need to be applied in different orders. Solution 3 is at best an optimization applied on top of solution 2, combining effects that can be combined. There are some effects that can be combined without with generating shaders. [For example a 3DLUT can be a solution for a many effects](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-post-processing-3dlut.html)

Comment: Thanks for all of you. As you guys saying, I'll go with third one. 
And specially thanks to the materials. It really helps!